# Used as a verb/the verb/verbs

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural

> 1. Option A and Option B are used **as a verb/the verb/verbs**.

In the above sentence, will we use "used as a verb", "used as the verb", or "used as verbs"? I want to know if "used as a verb" or "used as the verb" is correct or not, because both options A and B indicate towards the same thing that is "a verb".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that it all depends. It depends on the context - what you are going on to say.

For an easy illustration, instead of **a verb**, use **a hammer** as it's much simpler to make up appropriate examples:

> The camper used **a** stone **as a hammer** to knock the pegs into the ground.
>   (Indefinite articles before an unspecified items)
>
> The campers used stones **as hammers** to knock the pegs into the ground.
>   (No article required before plural items)
>
> The campers used **the stones** lying around as hammers.
>   (Definite article before specified items)
>
> The campers used stones **as the hammers** that were later found with blood marks.
>   (Definite article before specified objects)

The same rules apply if you were making up sentences with the word **verb**. So you could talk about:

**the word used as a verb**
**the words used as verbs**   or
**the words used as the verbs that fitted the context**.

In your example, the answer depends on the context:

> Option A and Option B are used **as the verbs** expected by the teacher.
>   Option A and Option B are used **as verbs** rather than nouns.

https://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/articles.aspx